# Add Comment after every 200 words of a node

Tags: comments

I am creating a creative writing feedback site and would like the option for feedback to be given after every 200 words of the body of one particular node type I'm calling chapter. The writer would post an entire chapter, but then when a user wants to give feedback the node would display like this:

The first 200 words of this chapter would go here

-Add Comment

The second 200 words of this chapter would go here

-Add Comment

The third 200 words of this chapter would go here

-Add Comment

And so on and so forth. I've found the pagination module that will break up the node body into specific length sections, each with comment form, but I want to be able to display multiple 200-word sections on each page.

Any idea on how I might accomplish this function?

Comment: I cant find a proper Drupal way to accomplish this. If i do i will go with some javascript to show comment form and AJAX submit.